# in my IIS log files cookies is not getting stored

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, cookies

My Cookie is not getting stored in the IIS logs when accessing  the ssl protected webservice. it is storing the cookie if it is not ssl protected.Is there any configuration do I need to set up ?

Comment: cookies are not stored on IIS logs, maybe you mean saved somehow on the log ?

Comment: sample :  2014-07-17 11:47:04 W3SVC3 DEMO 10.xx.xx.01 GET /favicon.ico - 444 - 10.xx.xx.01  HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) cookie=0r8s27WDTQN2KxqxaD8LFDje - test.com:444 401 2 5 6709 498 30